# Python shell freezes on reading (fasta) file

Tags: python, shell, freeze, fasta

I am going to start of by showing the code I have thus far:

```
def err(em):
    print(em)
    exit

def rF(f):
    s = ""
    try:
        fh = open(f, 'r')
    except IOError:
        e = "Could not open the file: " + f
        err(e)

    try:
        with fh as ff:
            next(ff)
            for l in ff:
                if ">" in l:
                    next(ff)
                else:
                    s += l.replace('\n','').replace('\t','').replace('\r','')
    except:
        e = "Unknown Exception"
        err(e)
    fh.close()
    return s
```

For some reason the python shell (I am using 3.2.2) freezes up whenever I tried to read a file by typing:

```
rF("mycobacterium_bovis.fasta")
```

The conditionals in the rF function are to prevent reading each line that starts with a ">" token. These lines aren't DNA/RNA code (which is what I am trying to read from these files) and should be **ignored**.

I hope anyone can help me out with this, I don't see my error.

As per the usual, MANY thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
**The problem persists!**
This is the code I now use, I removed the error handling which was a fancy addition anyway, still the shell freezes whenever attempting to read a file. This is my code now:

```
def rF(f):
    s = ""
      try:
          fh = open(f, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print("Err")

    try:
        with fh as ff:
            next(ff)
            for l in ff:
                if ">" in l:
                    next(ff)
                else:
                    s += l.replace('\n','').replace('\t','').replace('\r','')
    except:
        print("Err")

    fh.close()
    return s
```

Comment: `e` is never defined in `rF`.

Comment: **thank you!!** I can't believe I missed that! On the other hand it is one of these little things that are easily overlooked. But yea, you saved the day!

Comment: Perhaps you could answer the question so I can mark your answer as the answer to this question...

Comment: That method of string-concatentation is known to be very slow. Consider perhaps writing to a file instead.

Comment: About how many lines are in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't ever define `e`.
So you'll get a NameError that is being hidden by the naked `except:`.

This is why it is good and healthy to specify the exception, e.g.:

```
try: 
    print(e)
except NameError as e: 
    print(e)
```

In cases like yours, though, when you don't necessarily know what the exception will be you should at least use [this method of displaying information about the error](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions):

```
import sys
try:
    print(e)
except: # catch *all* exceptions
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print(e)
```

Which, using the original code you posted, would have printed the following:

```
name 'e' is not defined
```

---

Edit based on updated information:
Concatenating a string like that is going to be quite slow if you have a large file.
Consider instead writing the filtered information to another file, e.g.:

```
def rF(f):
  with open(f,'r') as fin, open('outfile','w') as fou:
    next(fin)
    for l in fin:
      if ">" in l:
        next(fin)
      else:
        fou.write(l.replace('\n','').replace('\t','').replace('\r',''))
```

I have tested that the above code works on a FASTA file based on the format specification listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format using Python 3.2.2 [GCC 4.6.1] on linux2.

A couple of recommendations:

- Start small.  Get a simple piece working then add a step.
- Add `print()` statements at trouble spots.

Also, consider including more information about the contents of the file you're attempting to parse. That may make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Ouch! I am sorry to say but the problem still isn't resolved, even after removing the error handling (which was more of a fancy addition anyway) the shell still freezes up.